# Change controller and action name in ASP.NET MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I created an areas -> Admin.

In my register area, I have:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I changed it to:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "jojo",
    "jojo/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now if you type in a URL, `xxx/jojo/AdminHome/Index`, it works perfectly, but how can I change the controller and action names until the user can not finds that it's going to the admin area. Notice that I do not want change my controller name to jojo, for example.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: i mean how can i change my controller and action name from real (class name) to fake name until hackers can not realize real names

Comment: There is no point in doing that.  Security by obscurity is generally useless.  Instead, use authentication and SSL.  (And don't allow XSS or SQL injection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "jojo",
    "jojo/jojo/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller="RealController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```